# C bit counting causes unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, linux, binary, binary-data

I was writing a Hamming weight function in C. I wanted to know if I did it correctly, so my plan was to test on the number 5. I didn't want to google the binary for 5 and wrote some code to do it myself, however when I ran the code I got this:

```
testing code
bit length of 5: 32

five: -1354390872 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

This didn't make sense as nothing should be able to output such a large negative number.
Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
      printf("\ntesting code\n");
      int fv[32];
      int fiv = 5;
      for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            if (fiv & 1) fv[32 - i] = 1; else fv[32 - i] = 0;
            fiv >>= 1;
      }
      printf("bit length of 5: %ld\n\n", (sizeof(5) * 8));
      printf("five: ");
      for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            printf("%d ", fv[i]);
      }
      printf("\n");
      return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to populate the array with integers 0 or 1 where the array would represent the binary value of the number. It certainly populated the array with 32 bit integers representing the number, however -1354390872 is not 0, nor 1. I've tried changing the number I iterate through to be `(sizeof(n) * 8` to account for the size of a byte, however that just hangs and I couldn't figure it out as there is no manpage for `sizeof()`. I also tried replacing the line where I set `fv[32 - i]` to this unoptimised mess: `if (fiv & 1) fv[32 - i] = 1; else fv[32 - i] = 0;` in hopes that it would change the output

Can someone help, I'm sure there's a binary format that I don't know about that I could be using, but I honestly don't know it.

Edit: Running the code multiple times gives completely random outputs of very large numbers. Example:

```
testing code
bit length of 5: 32

five: -956652888 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
forward:~/cproblem/declareyourvariablesc $ ./main

testing code
bit length of 5: 32

five: -754855256 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
forward:~/cproblem/declareyourvariablesc $ ./main

testing code
bit length of 5: 32

five: 104133288 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
forward:~/cproblem/declareyourvariablesc $ ./main

testing code
bit length of 5: 32

five: -1662766424 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
forward:~/cproblem/declareyourvariablesc $ ./main

testing code
bit length of 5: 32

five: -103538008 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
forward:~/cproblem/declareyourvariablesc $ ./main

testing code
bit length of 5: 32

five: 1071841960 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: `fv[32 - i]` is out-of-bounds when `i` is zero hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: thank you! forgot that I can do `i = 32; i > 0; i--` instead

Comment: You don't have to store the bits in an array for the hamming weight. You could just increment a counter. There are much faster ways also you can find easily here on SO.

Comment: This code was out of context, my Hamming weight function doesn't store the bits in an array and just increments a counter. This code was so that I could see what the binary representation of 5 is. Here's the Hamming Weight code:
`int c = 0;`
      `for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (sizeof(n) * 8); i++) {`
           `if (n & 1) c++;`
            `n >>= 1;`
      `}`
      `return c;`

Comment: You can just use fv[32 - i] = fiv & 1 and do away with the branching if.

Comment: When doing bit operations, it is better to use unsigned ints to avoid problems with the sign bit.

Comment: OT: `%ld` --> `%zu`

Comment: @synnøve You won't find a manpage for `sizeof` since it's an operator, not a library function.

Comment: If you just need the count, and the value being counted is an unsigned integer (or a positive signed integer), you could do: `int count = 0;` `while (value != 0) {` `count++;` `value &= value - 1;` `}`. Note that `value &= value - 1;` changes the lowest `1` bit to a `0` bit by the properties of binary arithmetic.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `fv[32 - i]`, you should use `fv[32 - 1 - i]` to avoid accessing beyond the end of the array.  As posted, the code has undefined behavior, which explains the observed output, but anything else could happen too.

To void these computations, you can use a down loop (**note the use of the postdecrement operator in `i--`**):

```
      for (int i = 32; i-- > 0;) {
          if (fiv & 1)
              fv[i] = 1;
          else
              fv[i] = 0;
          fiv >>= 1;
      }
```

And you can simplify the loop body:

```
      for (int i = 32; i-- > 0;) {
          fv[i] = fiv & 1;
          fiv >>= 1;
      }
```

Also note that `sizeof(5)` is the size in byte of type `int` and has type `size_t` which may be different from `unsigned long`. `size_t` requires the conversion `%zu` for `printf`. To avoid compatibility issues on legacy systems, I recommend casting the `size_t` expression as `(unsigned)` and using `%u`.  Also note that `* 8` assume 8-bit bytes, which are quite ubiquitous today, except for some DSPs and ancient CPUs.  Purists would use `CHAR_BIT` defined in `<limits.h>`.

Here is the modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("\ntesting code\n");

    int fv[32];
    int fiv = 5;

    for (int i = 32; i-- > 0;) {
        fv[i] = fiv & 1;
        fiv >>= 1;
    }
    printf("bit length of 5: %u\n\n", (unsigned)(sizeof(5) * 8));
    printf("five: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        printf("%d ", fv[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! now a different issue happens where it doesn't output anything, progress!:
`testing code`
`bit length of 5: 32`
`five:`

Comment: @synnøve: you might have broken something... try the code from my answer.

Answer (score 4):

@chqrlie already answered the correct solution.

Just to explain what is happening here:
Since `fv` is defined locally in the `main` function and is not set to zero, its values are undefined.
Your `for` loop iterates from `0` to `31` so you are changing the values of `fv` at position `32` to `1`.
Position `32` is out of range and results in undefined behavior.

But in particular the position `0` was never written keeping its "random" value.